# Как сделать сжатие хлебных крошек?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Добрый день, может кто сталкивался с необходимостью урезать хлебные крошки? Подскажите как сделать такое? урезать текст в центре?  [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/Yd5eS/)

[image]

Comment: z-index + box-shadow + немного js.

Comment: Чего велосипедить? Вот [готовое решение](http://vremenno.net/js/breadcrumbs-using-jquery/)

Comment: @Deonis если вы внимательно посмотрите картинку ТС, то поймете, что ваш пример на половину не точный.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GNAkn/6/

Соответственно чтобы сделать правую часть каждой ссылки стреловидной, вам нужно нарисовать своё изображение, которое будет служить фоном. Плюс все размеры подогнаны, вам нужно будет сообразить, как сделать универсальный меню-слайдер.

Я вообще чувствую, что моя реализация не самая удачная.

Comment: в полне годная реализация, единственная оптимизация, которую я вижу это использование [jQuery.single](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/76-bytes-for-faster-jquery/)

Comment: @Spectre не, я уверен, что можно как-то проще сделать, с одной анимацией.

Comment: одну анимацию для 2-х разных(пускай и "родственных") элементов? интересно посмотреть на это.

возможно использовать [.addClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) из jQuery UI

Comment: @Spectre не не) я совсем по другому думал это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно пригодиться вот такой еще код, http://jsfiddle.net/QQXZm/4/ в нем не обязательно подгонять все слова под одну ширину, длинна слова или словосочетания может быть любым, при это без переездов на строку ниже.

Comment: Два недочета.

Во-первых: наводим на первое меню - едут все меню.

Во-вторых: как вы и сказали, везде разная ширина.

Comment: Ну не знаю, ваш скрипт мне понравился единственно смутило то что при увеличении слов в одном из пунктов меню происходил перенос на другую строку. Вот этоn баг я и хотел доработать и не много оптимизировать код. А что касается того что едут все меню, ту так в вашем варианте они точно так-же и едут,  да и задачи не стояло это устранить,  по-моему так даже эффектнее смотриться! (тестил в Chrome, opera, IE9)